# .htaccess rewrite even if file exists

Tags: .htaccess

I want to serve my images as webp format. I am using a php script for this. But I can't execute rewrite condition if file exists.

```
# .htaccess code
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^((lib|uploads)/.+)\.(jpe?g|png)$ incs/webp.php?file=$1.$3 [L]
```

```
# this not works, showing existing original image
https://example.com/lib/image_exists.png

# this is works, showing PHP script output
https://example.com/lib/image_not_exists.png
```

I tried with existed image rewrite to my image convert script, but it's don't worked. But when I try not existed file, it's works.

It's works when file don't exists. I know my code is works, I tested too many ways. My problem just "how can I use RewriteRule when request URL matches an existing file". Apache don't execute RewriteRule when URL matching an existing file.

PS: I tested localhost and another server and it's works. My server is auto installed by [HestiaCP](https://hestiacp.com). Can someone explain to me what is wrong on my server? (all others works in .htaccess file, just don't work if URL matches an existing file)

#SOLVED
It's was my server's problem. NGINX proxy have priority for static files. [here is the solution](https://forum.hestiacp.com/t/htaccess-rewriterule-doesnt-work-if-url-matching-an-exists-file/8015)

Comment: Are you getting 404 for `/lib/image_exists.png`? Can you show your full .htaccess in question

Comment: No, I show the original image. The real problem is last line don't work if /lib/image_exist.png already exists. The rest of the htaccess file has nothing to do with this problem.
[link](https://gist.github.com/aktolu/13d646ad9d989025eadeff1018182940)

Comment: It may be a browser cache issue. Did you try clearing browser cache?

Comment: @anubhava Yes. Also I have using ctrl + f5 combination, private window, etc. It's works when file don't exists. I know my code is works, I tested too many ways. My problem just "how can I use `RewriteRule` when request URL matches an existing file". Apache don't execute `RewriteRule` when URL matching an existing file.